# Add mean and SD to a CrossTable in R

Tags: r, mean, crosstab

I have a CrossTable for Gender vs Age from a survey and I need to add the mean for the Age and the SD for it as well.

```
crosstab(paste(subtPadres1$Edad, "años"), subtPadres1$Genero, prop.c = T, plot = F, dnn = c("Edad", "Género"))
```

This is the result:

[image]

How can I add those parameters into the crosstab below the last Age (16 yo)?

Comment: Which package are you using for `crosstab()`? Functions with that name show up in `descr`, `janitor`, `misty` and several other packages.

Comment: I use descr as package, but I don't think if I could add the mean age and the SD above the Total...